# Creating a new Boolean column after group by?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame 'data', I would like to add the Boolean variable B as column in data. But I would like for it to be calculated for subgroups of the data frame data.

Here's the data frame

```
data_ = {'ID': [777, 777, 777,777,777,777],'Month':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'Salary': [130,170,50,140,180,60], 'O': ["ACC","BRU","BRU","ACC","BRU","BRU"], 'D':["LFW","ACC","LFW","LFW","ACC","LFW"]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=data_)
```

Here's B
& the grouping for the two subgroups

```
data.groupby(['ID','Month'])
B= (data["O"]==data["D"].shift(-1)) | (data["D"]==data["O"].shift(1))
data["B"]= B
```

[image]

The last step would be to add for each sub-group the `Salary` where `B is False` to the `Salary` in the two rows where `B is True`

```
  data1=data[data["B"]==True]
  data2=data[data["B"] == False]
  data["Salary"]=data["Salary"]+ data2["Salary"]
```

[image]

I don't know exactly how to group the dataframe, add B based on the content in rows of each group and then add the salaries together based on the values of B.
Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: can you provide the expected output for Salary? What you want is unclear

Comment: Hi @mozway, thank you for your answer and comment. I added a new picture of the expected new salary. Basically the salary of the rows where B is True will be updated with the value of the salary where B is false. for example first row from first group is 130+ 50

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`GroupBy.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
g = data.groupby(['ID','Month'])

data['B'] = data['O'].eq(g['D'].shift(-1)) | data['D'].eq(g['O'].shift(1))
```

output:

```
    ID  Month  Salary    O    D      B
0  777      1     130  ACC  LFW   True
1  777      1     170  BRU  ACC   True
2  777      1      50  BRU  LFW  False
3  777      2     140  ACC  LFW   True
4  777      2     180  BRU  ACC   True
5  777      2      60  BRU  LFW  False
```